# How to sort a list based on another list with integers Python

Tags: python

So, I'm generally new at programming, and I was just wondering if it was possible to sort a list based not on the positions of another list, but the actual integers itself?

```
#Here is my list to be sorted
sent = ['Ho','Hi','Hi','Ho','Hi','Ho','!','Hi']

#The positions I will sort by
pos = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]

#The output I want is
sortlst = ['Hi','Ho','Ho','Hi','Hi','Hi','Ho','!']
```

I have tried searching for methods to resolve this, but could not find any. List comprehensions and the like has been able to call elements in sent, but not by the actual integers of pos, rather the position.

```
for i in pos:
    T.append(sent[i])
recreate = " ".join(T) 
print (recreate)
```

Running this segment will output:

```
Ho Ho Ho Ho Ho Ho Ho Hi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain more concretely what you mean by "sort a list based not on the positions of another list, but the actual integers itself?" You appear to mean the "occurrence of the unique elements" but it's not clear.

Comment: So far I have managed to understand that in the second list 1 means `Hi`, 2 means `Ho` and 3 means `!`. But I'm not sure that really qualifies as sorting as instead you are basically replacing numbers with strings

Comment: You sure you have all your code posted, because from what I've read this is very incomplete and doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Did you invent or formulate the problem yourself or is there a specification you could share with us?

Comment: @UnholySheep That is essentially what I wish to do, to replace each unique integer with a string. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: You could just create some mapping between integer values and string (e.g.: using a dictionary). assuming that dictionary would be called `iToStr` you'd then simply have a list comprehension: `sortLst = [iToStr[i] for i in pos]`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
sent = ['Hi', 'Ho', '!']
pos = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
recreate = [sent[i - 1] for i in pos]
print(recreate)
# ['Hi', 'Ho', 'Ho', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', '!']
```

However it requires you to describe the table with 'signs' (`sent = ['Hi', 'Ho', '!']` here) that would be matched in order with numbers. 1 to 'Hi', 2 to 'Ho' and 3 to '!', etc.

Comment: Thanks alot. Very Helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I will make a few assumptions for my proposed solution.

- `pos` has 7 elements but `sortlst` has 8. I assume this is a typo.
- You associate each *unique* element of `sent` with an integer based on its sorted value. Note, though, that you sort '!' as *after* 'Ho', even though it is *before* in lexicographical order. I will use lexicographical order unless you propose an alternative.

Therefore, `post = [1,2,3]` is telling me:

> Give me an array with the first, second, and third unique sorted values of `sent`.

With this definition in mind:

```
>>> sent = ['Ho','Hi','Hi','Ho','Hi','Ho','!','Hi']
>>> pos = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
>>> elements = sorted(set(sent))
>>> elements
['!', 'Hi', 'Ho']
>>> [elements[i - 1] for i in pos]
['!', 'Hi', 'Hi', '!', '!', '!', 'Ho']
```